# How to properly implement hover effect on icon links in Nuxt.js

Tags: events, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement a hover effect on an icon link for a component in a site built using Nuxt.js with Bootstrap 4. I've attempted using the @mouseover/@mouseenter and @mouseleave events to switch the src attribute from one icon image to another, but it doesn't cause a change unless the icon link is clicked. Does this have something to do with focus? Is there a better way to get the effect I want? 
The component is below.

```
<template>
    <b-row class="main-focus px-3 pt-3">
        <b-col md="12" class="mb-4">
            <h1 class="clr-t mb-4 px-2 pb-1 clr-brdr-btm">resume</h1>
            <p class="drk-t pl-2">{{description[0].text}}</p>
            <b-link 
                @mouseover="icon = 'assets/images/icons/resume-icon-clicked.svg'"
                @mouseleave="icon = 'assets/images/icons/resume-icon.svg'"
                :href="resume.url" 
                target="_blank"
            >
                <b-img 
                    class="icon bg-lt" 
                    v-bind="iconProps" 
                    rounded 
                    :src="icon"/>
            </b-link>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            description: Array,
            resume: Object
        },
        data () {
            return {
                icon: 'assets/images/icons/resume-icon.svg',
                iconProps: { width: 100 }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above behaviour is because b-link supports only @click event as stated in [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/link/).
You can achieve the functionality by wrapping b-link in a div as below.

```
    <div @mouseover="icon = 'assets/images/icons/resume-icon-clicked.svg'"
@mouseleave="icon = 'assets/images/icons/resume-icon.svg'">
    <b-link 
    :href="resume.url" 
    target="_blank"
    >
    <b-img 
    class="icon bg-lt" 
    v-bind="iconProps" 
    rounded 
    :src="icon"/>
    </b-link>
</div>
```